# Automating excel charts to PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Please i need assistance with a vba code for automating the process of coping excel charts into a power point slides followed by print button (excel charts to PPT).

I try recording a macro but i got error and i expected to copy excel charts to power point for presentation followed by a print button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA script to send charts from excel to specific slides in a powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255881/vba-script-to-send-charts-from-excel-to-specific-slides-in-a-powerpoint)

Comment: Welcome Thobelani! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour